# error while installing the angular cli

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm

When I am trying to install the angular client. I am getting the following error. I tried in implementing the suggestions of such similar issues from github, sof nothing seems to be worked out. Here is the issue.

[image]

Comment: run cmd as administrator.

Comment: Is it definately required? Because I dont have access for that.

Comment: I posted an answer below. Let me know if that works for you! :)

Comment: I tried. But it did not work and it is producing the same error.

Comment: Are you behind corporate proxy ?

Comment: @Venkat Yes.Most probably.

Comment: Try setting proxy, that may help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

And then it should work fine